# 1940s-ish SF short story — Moore? Brackett?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am pretty sure this story was written by a woman in the 1940s. I believe the locale is Venus; the planet is part of the Terran Empire, but the Empire is failing, and the Terran garrison is in retreat and about to abandon the planet entirely. The story is told from the point of view of a Venusian woman, the mistress of a Terran officer and a secret member of the underground. She has orders to assassinate the officer with (I remember this vividly) a glass knife that breaks up in the wound. I am pretty sure she is love with him and joins the retreat.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that this is not Brackett, but there are obviously lots of other planetary romance authors.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Google book search turned up **Journey to Infinity**, by Martin Greenberg, 1951.  Here's a snippet:

> Is the glass knife broken yet ? " “ Not yet , " said ... Watching the
> avid eyes fixed upon her all around the fire , she went on : “ The
> last Patrol is leaving Venus . ... Venus under Venusian rule , after
> three hundred years of Earth tyranny ! Is it true ...

Does it look right?  (Not a female author - but it is set on Venus and has a scene with a glass knife.)

**UPDATE**: May have also been published as a short-story in Astounding Science Fiction, Volume 28 Issue 6, 1942.  Here's a snippet from that:

> Venus under Venusian rule , after three They had risen - all but the
> hooded old one hundred years of Earth tyranny ! Is it true , not in
> deference ... One of the tribe leaders leaned forward , jutting Is the
> glass knife broken yet ? " a scarred , wolfish ...

The story itself is *[There Shall Be Darkness](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46523)* by C. L. Moore

Comment: @CL Moore : Yes, you are correct, Martin Greenberg is the editor of an anthology including this story.  My google book search skills leave something to be desired.

Comment: I think your searching skills are awesome: you found the story. You just need to write the name of the story and the author in your answer!

Comment: Thanks for the edit help Organic Marble! I appreciate it.

Comment: WHAT THE - ! I actually OWN a copy of 'Journey to Infinity' and I forgot this story was in it! Thank you for your help! And, speaking of Moore, don't forget she wrote 'Vintage Season', which is near the top of my all-time best list.

Comment: @Lee Eckhardt - Oh man!  Yeah, "Vintage Season" is one of my all time favorites as well!!

Comment: Robert Silverberg wrote 'In Another Country', a companion piece to Moore's story: the same story told from the point of view of different characters. It was interesting, but not up to 'Vintage Season'..

Comment: The second blockquote looks like it was scanned in two-column format and is now printed out of order.